# How can you set the logger name in Camel's errorHandler with type DeadLetterChannel?

Tags: exception, logging, apache-camel, apache-karaf

I trying to specify logger name for errorHandler with type DeadLetterChannel and have error about I can't use logName for this.

Is it possible to specify logger name?

or maybe it's bad practice use own logger name for dlc?

my config

```xml
<errorHandler id="myDeadLetterChannel" type="DeadLetterChannel" deadLetterUri="direct:deadLetterChannel" logName="MYLOGGERNAME">
    <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="5" retryAttemptedLogLevel="INFO" backOffMultiplier="2" useExponentialBackOff="true" />
</errorHandler>
```

Actual log message:

```sh
13:31:46,947 | INFO  | evMasterDbEvent] | DeadLetterChannel                176 | 144 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.12.0.redhat-610379 | Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID:tetra-backend-43331-1577539405267-13:6:2:1:1 on ExchangeId: ID-tetra-backend-38269-1577539416633-5-5). On delivery attempt: 0 caught: com.x.exception.BusinessLogicException: Unexpected event type ZZZ
```

Expected log message:

```sh
13:31:46,947 | INFO  | evMasterDbEvent] | MYLOGGERNAME                176 | 144 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.12.0.redhat-610379 | Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID:tetra-backend-43331-1577539405267-13:6:2:1:1 on ExchangeId: ID-tetra-backend-38269-1577539416633-5-5). On delivery attempt: 0 caught: com.x.exception.BusinessLogicException: Unexpected event type ZZZ
```

I also tried add CamelLogEipName and this way not change logger name in my situation...

```xml
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <properties>
    <property key="CamelLogEipName" value="MYLOGGERNAME"/>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make/found some solution but maybe Apache Camel support better solution?

Config:

```xml
<bean id="myRedeliveryPolicyConfig" class="org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryPolicy">
    <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="3" />
    <property name="backOffMultiplier" value="2" />
    <property name="useExponentialBackOff" value="true" />
    <property name="retryAttemptedLogLevel" value="WARN" />
</bean>

<bean id="myDeadLetterChannel" class="com.x.MyDeadLetterChannelBuilder">
    <property name="deadLetterUri" value="direct:deadLetterChannel"/>
    <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="myRedeliveryPolicyConfig"/>
    <property name="loggerName" value="MYLOGGERNAME"/>
</bean>

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="myEventTriggerRoute" errorHandlerRef="zDeadLetterChannel">
            <from uri="{{my.jmsVirtualTopic.myEventConsumer}}" />
            <process ref="myDbEventProcessor" />
        </route>

        <route>
            <from uri="direct:deadLetterChannel" />
            <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="Message added to dead letter queue" />
            <to uri="{{my.jms.myEventDeadLetterQueueIn}}" />
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

Custom DeadLetterChannelBuilder

```java
import org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel;
import org.apache.camel.builder.DeadLetterChannelBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class MyDeadLetterChannelBuilder extends DeadLetterChannelBuilder {

    private String loggerName;

    @Override
    protected CamelLogger createLogger() {
        return new CamelLogger(LoggerFactory.getLogger(loggerName), LoggingLevel.ERROR);
    }
}
```